# Encode video on Android and add watermark

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'd like to be able to record a video using Android 2.3.6 and later. After the recording is done I'd like to be able to add a watermark-image to the video, so that I can upload it to my server with the watermark included.

I guess that I have to re-encode the video somehow?!?
I read about using ffmpeg on android but from the ffmpeg site that I found I saw that it is working on Android Honeycomb and later. My problem is that I have to find a solution that also works with Android 2.3.6

Thanks for every hint

Comment: @George can you refer the site where you saw ffmpeg on android used for Honeycomb and later. Please share the URL.

Comment: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg and 
http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

Comment: well i am facing problems in building static executable from guardian project.

Comment: @Georg did you got any solution?